# Prevent element from occupying space before show up

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I want to switch between 2 elements in one place. When switching, current element will fade out, and after that, the next element will fade in to replace the old one. So I set a delay time for the .ng-hide-remove to get this effect.

But before the next element shows up, it occupies space in the DOM and breaks the layout of the page.

How can I fix this?

Here is the fiddle link: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnlinhlang/64hyecmj/3/)

css:

```
div {
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

#div1 {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#div2 {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.ng-hide-remove {
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Switch the DIVs: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheck"></h1>

<div id="div1" ng-hide="myCheck">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2" ng-hide="!myCheck">Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the transition on your div. See the forked fiddle here with the transition commented out.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z17zeho1/)

```
div {
 //  transition: all linear 0.5s;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I also want the fade-out effect.

Comment: my recommendation is to use https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. That way you don't have to do it yourself. I can update the fiddle later with that, but its pretty easy! You could have an ng-class and add the required class name based on 'myCheck'

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at it.